# Formula derivation in the CHOMP: Gradient Optimization Techniques for Efficient Motion Planning article

Tags: robotics, convex-optimization, motion-planning

Has anyone read this article, i.e., *CHOMP: Gradient Optimization Techniques for Efficient Motion Planning* article?

I'm confused about the derivation of equations 2-3, which is shown in the figure below.

A detailed procedure is expected. Besides, which chapter of Convex Optimization (S. Boyd and L. Vandenberghe) does this derivation belong to？

From which chapter of the book can I learn the derivation process?

Pic:

[image]